# Unable to read "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova/templates/common/index.html" file (Error code: ENOENT)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, yeoman

When running the generator-angular-cordova [1] yeoman generator, the following error occurs:

```
Unable to read "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova/templates/common/index.html" file (Error code: ENOENT).
```

[1] https://github.com/wangshijun/generator-angular-cordova

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for OS X

**1. Remove generator**

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova
```

**2. Clone git repo**

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ && git clone https://github.com/wangshijun/generator-angular-cordova.git
```

**3. Install dependencies**

```
cd generator-angular-cordova
npm install
```